# Is there a way to use Jenkins with Github Pull Requests?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, jenkins

I want Jenkins to automatically find and run the test suite for every branch that is part of an open pull request. Is this possible with some Jenkins plugin I have not found?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible to get Jenkins to check every branch. However, +1 for this question as I'd love to have this feature.

Comment: We use the "fork early, fork often" mentality so we would have a ton of unnecessary test executions.  I would really love to have the functionality of only seeing "branches preparing for integration" being tested.

Comment: There is https://gist.github.com/1911084 and https://github.com/cramerdev/jenkins-comments

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A new plugin has been released recently for [Jenkins—Github pull request builder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Github+pull+request+builder+plugin).

If it does what it says on the tin it's probably what you want.

Answer (score 7):

I found the Jenkins Github pull request builder plugin unusable, so I wrote a little daemon that synchronizes Jenkins jobs with PRs, then comments build status back to each PR's comment thread. You can find it here: https://github.com/percolate/jennifer

Comment: What was unusable about it?

Answer (score 2):

One method that should work is you could rename the branch when it is "prepared for integration" and ready to be tested.

A naming convention like prep/my_feature.

Then in the Jenkins git plugin you can configure the branch names that you want it to look at for building.  You can have it match 'prep/*'.

We used to do this for all our feature branches using a prefix of 'dev/' to mark the feature branches that should have the autobuild run for them.  Seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar, but where Jennifer is a node.js app, Jently is a Ruby app. You can find it at https://github.com/vaneyckt/Jently.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using Cloudbees, they offer their own pull request builder plugin.

https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Github+Pull+Request+Validation

The advantages they tout over the standard [Jenkins Github pull request builder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Github+pull+request+builder+plugin) is that it runs as a "tenant-isolate" program, preventing the code in the pull request from snooping around for passwords or ssh keys. I could see this being particularly useful for a public project.