# How can Jenkins builds be triggered by uploading code to a GitHub repository?

Tags: linux, git, github, jenkins

I am using Jenkins 2.8 on Ubuntu 16.  I have installed the GitHub Integration Plugin.  I have created a Jenkins build with the Build Trigger "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling."  I have pushed code to this repo on GitHub.com via Linux command line.  The Jenkins build does not start.  I expect it to be triggered.  I go to the job in Jenkins then I click on "GitHub Hook Log" and I see

> Last GitHub Push
>   Polling has not run yet.

When I go to my GitHub.com account -> Settings -> Integrations and Services, I see the "Jenkins (GitHub plugin)" service with a green check next to it.  I can click "Test service."  It seems to be connecting fine.

From the back end on the Linux server that runs the Jenkins deployment, I can do this: ssh git@github.com
I get a confirmation message.  Everything seems fine.

When I upload code to the repo on GitHub.com (e.g., from a Linux command line or from a web browser), I expect the Jenkins build to be triggered.  The Jenkins build has never polled.  Jenkins is not being triggered.  What should I do?

Comment: Pretty similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784329/how-can-i-make-jenkins-ci-with-git-trigger-on-pushes-to-master or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583055/is-there-a-way-to-use-jenkins-with-github-pull-requests

Comment: I recommend the thorough answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45121585/4200039

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger a Jenkins 2.0 Pipeline job from a GitHub pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850485/how-to-trigger-a-jenkins-2-0-pipeline-job-from-a-github-pull-request)